# Get ID of parent div of an iframe

Tags: html, jquery, iframe, parent

I have an iframe within same domain.

I am trying to get the id of the grand parent wrapper of the iframe using javascript code(code is written  inside the Iframe)

following is the code

```
<div class="iframe-inner-main-wrapper" id="myid-1">
    <div class="iframe-inner-wrapper">
        <iframe src="http://samedomain.com">
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>title i1</h1>
            </body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){     
                    var abc = jQuery('.iframe-inner-wrapper')closest(".iframe-inner-main-wrapper");
                    console.log(abc);         
                });
  
            </script>
            </html>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

I should have get the id as myid-1  but I get undefined

I have written javascript inside iframe because based on id I get I want to some task inside iframe

please help

Comment: Need to realize that an iframe has it's own window and document that is isolated from the parent window. The jquery shown is looking at the inner document

Comment: @charlietfl Is it possible what I am trying to acheive

Comment: Yes but you need to go up into the parent document first then look for that class